# Synchronization context not preserved with async/await?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I've recently changed some code to be asynchronous, using the async/await pattern.

This code is now creating an exception:

```
private async void Refresh(object stateInfo)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(HydrateServerPingDtoList);
    // more code here
}

private void HydrateServerPingDtoList()
{
    // more code here.
    // Exception occurs on this line:
    this._serverPingDtoList.Add(new ServerPingDto() { ApplicationServer = server });
}
```

The exception:

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its
>   SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

`_serverPingDtoList` is the backing field for a WPF-bound property. Since I thought that async-await preserved the synchronization context, why would I get this error?

Comment: I don't think it will do that in an explicit `StartNew`. What it will do is preserve the context of the generated continuation for `// more code here`

Comment: Shouldn't your signature be returning a `Task`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`await` restores the `SynchronizationContext` within its own `async` method. It will not propagate it to a background thread that you start via `StartNew`.

On a side note, `StartNew` should not be used in `async` code; I [explain why in detail](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) on my blog. You should use `Task.Run` to execute CPU-bound code.

However, any UI updates (including updates of data-bound properties) should be done on the UI thread, not on a background task. So, assuming that your `HydrateServerPingDtoList` is actually CPU-bound, you can do this:

```
private ServerPingDto HydrateServerPingDtoList()
{
  // more code here.
  return new ServerPingDto() { ApplicationServer = server };
}

private async Task Refresh(object stateInfo)
{
  var serverPingDto = await Task.Run(() => HydrateServerPingDtoList());
  this._serverPingDtoList.Add(serverPingDto);
  // more code here
}
```